# Can I use Google Charts to create this chart on a Visualforce page (see attached)?

Tags: visualforce, charts, google-apps

I'm looking to recreate these excel charts in a custom Force.com system. The issue I'm running into is that it's not possible using standard reporting to display side-by-side comparisons of rolling weekly averages for non-equal time periods (such as weekly average for current week vs current month vs 3 months rolling).

Would I be able to accomplish this using Google Charts in a Visualforce page? Or using Visualforce charting?

Thanks!
Stephanie

[image: charts]

Answer (score 7):

You could definitely do something like this with the flexibility of VF and Apex you could use Google charts, Visualforce charting tags or even a different visualization engine like [d3js.org](http://d3js.org/).

Here's a cookbook recipe, for instance: 
http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/easy-visualforce-charts-with-javascript-remoting--google-charts-api

Comment: Thanks! Do you have thoughts on whether Google charts or Visualforce charting is the better option to go with?

Comment: Depends on what you already know. I would argue that VF charting will be more intuitive if you've used a lot of Visualforce. There are a couple of tricky things, (like case sensitivity, where most of VF is case insensitive). But the google API is also straightforward and well documented. 

The heavy lifting will actually be in the Apex code as this is where you will need to construct the queries that will return the data that you want, and if you want it user-adjustable, more work there. Once you get through that, which UI library you use will be a trivial decision, I suspect.

Comment: In my experience google charting is a little more mature last time I tried VF charting.

Comment: @PhilB Visualforce Charting is more mature too than it was a few releases ago. That said, it boils down to "trusting an external API not to change" versus "using a documented internal API that will be supported as long as the version it was documented under is supported." Google doesn't use versions for their APIs, so something that works today might not six months down the road.